# How to fetch the changes(merge confliict) from pr to local?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Suppose I already had a branch and I committed the code and push the change to develop and after that, I created a new pr under the same branch and after pushing the code to the pr now, it is showing that merge conflict on pr but not in local,
two questions.

1. how to get those conflicts to the local machine?
2. how to get rid of these conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get the conflict to the local machine. Here is the command

```
git pull origin develop
```

git pull origin master will pull changes from the origin remote, and master branch and merge them to the local checked-out branch.

Second, once you get the conflicts to your local machine then you can compare the changes and keep the change whichever you want to keep, or you can update the changes as per your needs.

Comment: You don't need the `pull`, and since there is a known merge conflict you probably don't want it.  Just do a `fetch`.

Comment: But if you are just working with 2 machines, it sounds like you really just want to update master and rebase.

Comment: Will use once `fetch` and then confirm the same @WilliamPursell